# Using Slick Transaction under external transaction management

Tags: spring, scala, activiti

I want to use Slick transaction for managing [activiti](http://activiti.org/) transactional API calls.

Currently transactionManager for `activiti` is configured via its spring config as follow

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.SimpleDriverDataSource">
<property name="driverClass" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
<property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/mydb" />
<property name="username" value="abc" />
<property name="password" value="password" />
</bean> 
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
<property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

If I want to replace Spring's `DataSourceTransactionManager` with Slick TM, what's the best way to do it? I have scala object which is say `MyCompanyDataSource.getDb` which returns  `slick.driver.PostgresDriver.simple.Database`

Comment: Can you just feed the "dataSource" bean to Slick's `Database.forDataSource()` or perhaps `Database.forURL()` instead?